# update pagination with filter in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I have problems to update my pagination, I have already seen other post but I can not adapt it to my code, I have several filter fields (name, city, data)

i tried the $scope.watch or $timeout

```
 $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems/$scope.itemsPerPage);

 $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            //wait for 'filtered' to be changed
            /* change pagination with $scope.filtered */
            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.myData.length/$scope.viewby);
        }, 10);
    };
```

I think my problem is that I do not take the new size table after filter

I represent my ng-repeat like this, but I like I start and I see several ways to do I am a little dump but it works well apart the update

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in myData.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) | myfilter: startDate: endDate | filter:search">
```

i make plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/oLdRMAEhFPutYBV1TFYq?p=preview

if someone cal help me

thanks in advance

**EDIT :**

I would need a ng repeat like this so I can recover the size of the table sort but I can not adjust it to my table

```
 <li ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">{{data.name}}</li>
```

with this function

```
      $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            //wait for 'filtered' to be changed
            /* change pagination with $scope.filtered */
            $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.filtered.length/$scope.entryLimit);

        }, 10);
}
```

i thinks that i just need something like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in result =( myData.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) | myfilter: startDate: endDate | filter:search)">
```

miss me just the correctly syntax

Comment: No body can help me ??

Comment: ok it s resolved :D